# Why does my string get converted into a boolean when calling an overloaded function

Tags: c++, string, function, overloading

I have an overloaded function called `createValue`:

```
void createValue(string, string);
void createValue(string, int);
void createValue(string, double);
void createValue(string, bool);
```

When I call the method `obj->createValue("string name", "string value");`, it calls the `createValue(string, bool);` overload and stores my string as a boolean.

I have changed that overloaded function to use `char const*` instead of just `string` and it works but I would like to know why this happened?

Comment: Hint: What type is `"x"`? (It's not `std::string`).

Comment: `"string value"` is a string literal. When passed as an argument it decays into a `const char*`. Converting `const char*` to `bool` is a "better" conversion than the user-defined conversion to `std::string`, so the compiler chooses the last overload.

Comment: You sure the compiler isn't resolving string to char * to an int, then resolving your literal strings to a const char * -> int, and both end up devolving into the (string, bool) overload?

Comment: ah! okay my different vocab on the subject kept me from finding the answer here lol. Great help thanks!

Comment: @DavidW -- there is no standard conversion from `const char*` to `int`.

Comment: @Josefhu15 this is one question I don't mind seeing again. Even if you do know the "string literal is not a `string`" bit, you still must be very familiar with the nitty-gritty of conversion logic without already having encountered this problem in order to see it coming.